# Find the divisors of a number using Prolog by using recursion

Tags: prolog

I want to print the divisors of a number in Prolog and I have made the following code:

```
find_and_display_divisors(N) :-
    write('Divisors of '), write(N), write(':'), nl,
    find_divisors(N, 1).

find_divisors(N, D) :-
    D =< N,
    0 is N mod D,
    write(D), write(' '),
    NextD is D + 1,
    find_divisors(N, NextD).
find_divisors(_, _).
```

The problem that I have is that when I call my program with find_and_display_divisors(8), it only prints 1 2 true; however, it is missing the other values like 4 and 8. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that when it gets to 3, `0 is 8 mod 3` fails and triggers backtracking, that tries `find_divisors(_, _).` which succeeds and has no other instructions so ... that's it, success found, rule complete.

Comment: thank you @TessellatingHeckler I understand it, could you be so kind to help me with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a number is not a divisor, you still need to go to next step.
`find_divisors(_, _)` just stops the iteration at the first non-divisor.

So you will need a new clause covering the non-divisor part.

```
find_divisors(N, D) :-
    D =< N,
    M is N mod D,
    M > 0,
    NextD is D + 1,
    find_divisors(N, NextD).
```

You might want to include this if you want the predicate to succeed.

```
find_divisors(N, D) :- N < D.
```

PS: TA_intern's answer is idiomatic way to do it. Decouple side effects from logic code as much as possible.

Full working code:

```
find_and_display_divisors(N) :-
    write('Divisors of '), write(N), write(':'), nl,
    find_divisors(N, 1).

find_divisors(N, D) :-
    D =< N,
    0 is N mod D,
    write(D), write(' '),
    NextD is D + 1,
    find_divisors(N, NextD).

find_divisors(N, D) :-
    D =< N,
    M is N mod D, M > 0,
    NextD is D + 1,
    find_divisors(N, NextD).

find_divisors(N, D) :- N < D. % you can ignore this if you just need to print
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @rajashekar, but when I run this code in SW Prolog with find_and_display_divisors(8) I got: Divisors of 8: false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure all the clauses are there? you need to remove `find_divisors(_, _)`. and then add this clause.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need recursion to solve this problem. You are counting from 1 to N:

```
find_divisors(N, D) :-
    between(1, N, D),
    0 =:= N rem D.
```

```
?- find_divisors(8, D).
D = 1 ;
D = 2 ;
D = 4 ;
D = 8.
```

You say you need the side effect, the printing. Use backtracking and forall/2. You shouldn't have to embed the side effect within the logic:

```
?- forall(find_divisors(8, D), writeln(D)).
1
2
4
8
true.
```

If you want to write recursive code find a problem that is easier to solve using a recursive algorithm.

And, be ready to be surprised if you use `is/2` for *comparison*. It is meant for evaluating an arithmetic expression! `=:=/2` is for comparison.

```
?- 1 =:= sin(pi/2).
true.

?- 1 is sin(pi/2).
false.
```

Comment: "`find_divisors`" sounds so imperative. in such a declarative code, just `divisor/2` could sound better.